# Stop OpenLayers2 to Load Tiles at Certain Zoom Levels

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers

I want to use client zoom with OpenLayers2. However if I try this example http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/clientzoom.html the tiles turn red after two seconds when I try to zoom further than the maximum zoom level. It seems that OpenLayers tries to load tiles that are not there. I get this console message:

```
GEThttps://b.tile.openstreetmap.de/-1/0/213918.png
GEThttps://b.tile.openstreetmap.de/-1/0/213917.png
GEThttps://a.tile.openstreetmap.de/-1/0/213919.png
```

Maybe stopping OpenLayers trying to load new tiles at a certain zoom level will solve this. Unfortunately I haven't found a solution to this. Do you know another way?

This is my init function:

```
function init_map() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    
    basemap = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("dummy",
    ["https://a.tile.openstreetmap.de/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
    "https://b.tile.openstreetmap.de/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
    "https://c.tile.openstreetmap.de/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"],
    {
    resolutions: [156543.03390625, 78271.516953125, 39135.7584765625,
                  19567.87923828125, 9783.939619140625, 4891.9698095703125,
                  2445.9849047851562, 1222.9924523925781, 611.4962261962891,
                  305.74811309814453, 152.87405654907226, 76.43702827453613,
                  38.218514137268066, 19.109257068634033, 9.554628534317017,
                  4.777314267158508, 2.388657133579254, 1.194328566789627,
                  0.5971642833948135, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05],
    serverResolutions: [156543.03390625, 78271.516953125, 39135.7584765625,
                        19567.87923828125, 9783.939619140625,
                        4891.9698095703125, 2445.9849047851562,
                        1222.9924523925781, 611.4962261962891,
                        305.74811309814453, 152.87405654907226,
                        76.43702827453613, 38.218514137268066,
                        19.109257068634033, 9.554628534317017,
                        4.777314267158508, 2.388657133579254,
                        1.194328566789627, 0.5971642833948135],
    transitionEffect: 'resize'
    });
    map.addLayer(basemap);
    
    map.events.register('zoomend', map, function() {
        if(map.getZoom() > 18){
            var zoomInfo = 'Zoom level=' + map.getZoom();
            console.log(zoomInfo);
        }
    })
    
    epsg4326 =  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    projectTo = map.getProjectionObject();
    
    markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
    vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay");
    
    map.addLayer(markers);
    map.setCenter(
        new OpenLayers.LonLat( stations[0][0][1], stations[0][0][0] ).transform(epsg4326, projectTo),18
    );
    
    //----------Station-----------
    add_marker(score);
}
```

Comment: Please include the code you are using.  There must be an error as it is trying to load tiles at zoom level -1 which does not exist.

Comment: I added my code

Comment: Are you using version 2.13.1?  Earlier versions might not support client zoom.

Comment: Thats it! I used 2.11 Thank you!